# Why MAVLink Protocol is not secure?

Tags: security, networking, network-programming

`Unmanned Aircraft Systems` (UAS) are the systems based `Micro Air Vehicle communication Protocol` i.e. Drones, tinyCopters are based on MAVLink Protocol

but Why MAVLink Protocol is not secure?

How packet forwarding attacks, eavesdropping, and hijacking these constraints have issues in security of Protocol?

THank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mavlink Protocol does not provide any security. There is no confidentiality, or authentication mechanisms and while there are integrity mechanisms (CRC and packet count) these are for data loss not secure tamper checking.

While the Mavlink Protocol is not secure, it can be encapsulated in other secure protocols, such as DTLS, to ensure that Mavlink packets are delivered securely.

Comment: Is Man-in-the-middle attack avoidable using [Fuzzing Method](https://securewww.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/article-2667.pdf)? How can MAVLink protocol encapsulate? Please eleborate more...Thank You

Comment: 1) [Reference 4](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA598977) of the paper you linked to explains all the security concerns in greater detail. 2) the Fuzzing Method will not avoid attacks directly, it is just a method for finding new vulnerabilities. 3) [TLS and DTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) are used to encrypt TCP and UDP traffic, through encapsulation (read the wiki page for tech details).